# Work Manager isn't working when app is closed?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-workmanager, background-service

I have been stuck on this, I just want to make a simple application which changes wallpaper on the basis of time.

I have tried

- Work Manager with Periodic Request - Problem with this solution is that work manager isn't working after user closes the app.

Can anybody please give me a legit solution ?

Comment: Few questions:
What do you mean with "user closes the app"? are you putting the application in background or are you swiping it out from recent apps or are you force stopping it?
On which device are you experiencing this problem?
Have you looked into WorkManager's logging information available?
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

Comment: When I say "user closes the app" - I mean I am swiping it out of the recent apps. Though, I will check the link given by you, but if you've got any thing else also please send it over. Thanks!

Comment: Go though this: https://dontkillmyapp.com/problem

Answer (score 0):

Use chain of OneTimeWorkRequests with continuation in work manager that will do.